# Probability in DNA segmentation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I have formulated these questions ss part of a research in medical science (DNA segmentation):

1. A series of $M$ identical balls is arranged on a line. A partition is formed by placing a stick to the left $i$'th ball (zero partition is allowed so is partition with all of the balls, i.e., $0<i<M+1$). Now, given M balls and N sticks uniformly distributed on the array (that is, each stick is randomly placed anywhere, and two sticks could be placed at the same site) what is the probability $P(k)$ to find a segment of length $k$. **If its any help $N\ll M$
2. In a bag there are m balls, $b$ of them are black. In every try you take one ball and return it to the bag. What is the probability to get at least $k$ black balls in $n$ attempts? what is the probability to get at least $k$ different black balls (assumed that they are marked) what is the average number of black balls extracted (unique and in general)?
3. You throw balls into $m$ boxes of different sizes (the probability to get in to each box is equivalent to the box's size {$p_1,p_2...,p_m$} ). What is the probability that after $n$ throws you will have at least $k$ balls in a given sub group of $b$ boxes (with probabilities {$p_{b1}, p_{b2},...,p_{bb}$}). What is the probability that at least $k$ boxes will have at least $1$ ball in them. What are the averages?

Many thanks to all the helpers!

Comment: "probability $P(k)$ to find a segment of length $k$" You don't mean of "length greater on equal than $k$", no?

Comment: BTW, these are really three independent questions

Answer (score 1):

$1$. This can be calculated using the [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) technique and the [Inclusion-Exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Let $A_i,\; i=1,\ldots, N+1$ be the set of arrangements (of balls and sticks) such that the $i^{th}$ segment has length $k$. Then define the set of *all* arrangements with a segment of length $k$:

$$S = \bigcup_{i=1}^{N+1}{A_i}.$$

We want to find $\vert S \vert$. By inclusion-exclusion:

$$\vert S \vert = \sum_{i=1}^{N+1}{\vert A_i \vert} - \sum_{i\lt j}{\vert A_i \cap A_j \vert} + \sum_{i\lt j \lt l}{\vert A_i \cap A_j \cap A_l \vert} - \ldots - (-1)^{N+1} \bigg| \bigcap_{i=1}^{N+1}{A_i} \bigg|.$$

Consider the members of $A_i$. We have $N$ segments (all except the $i^{th}$ segment) into which we can place $M-k$ balls in any way. This is the same as arranging $M-k$ stars and $N-1$ bars in a line. The number of ways to do this is:

$$\vert A_i \vert = \binom{M+N-k-1}{M-k}.$$

There are $\binom{N+1}{1}$ such quantities to sum.

For $A_i \cap A_j, \; i \lt j$, we have $N-1$ segments into which we can place $M-2k$ balls. This is the same as arranging $M-2k$ stars and $N-2$ bars, so we have:

$$\vert A_i \cap A_j \vert = \binom{M+N-2k-2}{M-2k}.$$

There are $\binom{N+1}{2}$ such quantities to sum.

The general term, with the intersection of $a$ sets, is:

$$\bigg| A_{i_1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{i_a} \bigg| = \binom{M+N-ak-a}{M-ak} \quad\text{if $M \geq ak, \;$ otherwise it is $0$}.$$

There are $\binom{N+1}{a}$ such quantities to sum.

Note that it's possible, if $a = \frac{M}{k} = N+1$, to have a binomial coefficient of $\binom{-1}{0}$. This equals $1$.

So now we have,

$$\vert S \vert = \sum_{a = 1}^{N+1}{\binom{N+1}{a}\binom{M+N-ak-a}{M-ak}}.$$

Now the *total* number of arrangements of $M$ balls in $N+1$ segments, using a similar stars and bars argument, is

$$\binom{M+N}{M}.$$

So the required probability is:

$$P(\text{A segment of length $k$}) = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{a = 1}^{N+1}{(-1)^{a+1}\binom{N+1}{a}\binom{M+N-ak-a}{M-ak}}} {\binom{M+N}{M}}.$$

$\\$

As an example, if $M=6,\; N=2,\; k=2$, we get a resulting probability of $\dfrac{13}{28}$.

---

$\\$

$2\,(a)$. By the Binomial Theorem, the probability of getting at least $k$ black balls, not necessarily distinct, is

$$P(\text{At least $k$ black balls}) = \sum_{j=k}^n{\binom{n}{j} \left(\frac{b}{m}\right)^j \left(\frac{m-b}{m}\right)^{n-j}}.$$

$\\$

$2\,(b)$. For the probability of at least $k$ distinct black balls, it is more difficult. We calculate the number of ways to get *exactly* $k$ distinct black balls, then we can sum those results appropriately.

To count the number of ways to get exactly $k$ of the black balls, it's easier if we know exactly *which* $k$ balls. So suppose we nominate $k$ particular black balls. There are $\binom{b}{k}$ ways to do this, which is a fact we'll use later.

We look for the number of ways to draw $n$ balls such that only the $k$ nominated black balls and the $m-b$ non-black balls ($m-b+k$ balls in total) appear and with each of the $k$ black balls appearing at least once.

Let $D_i, \; i=1,\ldots,k$, be the set of draws (of $n$ balls) that contain the $i^{th}$ nominated black ball at least once. Then define the set

$$S_k = \bigcap_{i=1}^k{D_i}$$ which is the set of draws we need: every draw in $S_k$ has all $k$ nominated black balls.

In fact, we need just the cardinality of $S_k$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\bigg| S_k \bigg| &=& \bigg| \bigcap_{i=1}^k{D_i} \bigg| \\
&=& \bigg| \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^k{D_i^c} \right)^c \bigg| \qquad\text{by de Morgan's Laws} \\
&=& \bigg| \Omega_k \bigg| - \bigg| \bigcup_{i=1}^k{D_i^c} \bigg| \qquad\text{where $\Omega_k$ is the set of all draws from the $m-b+k$ balls} \\ \\
&=& \bigg| \Omega_k \bigg| - \left[ \sum_{i=1}^k{\vert D_i^c \vert} - \sum_{i\lt j}{\vert D_i^c \cap D_j^c \vert} + \sum_{i\lt j \lt l}{\vert D_i^c \cap D_j^c \cap D_l^c \vert} - \ldots - (-1)^k \bigg| \bigcap_{i=1}^k{D_i^c} \bigg| \right] \\
&&\qquad\text{by the Inclusion-Exclusion principle.} \\ \\
\end{eqnarray*}

$\vert \Omega_k \vert = (m-b+k)^n$ since each ball in the draw can be any one of $m-b+k$ balls.

The other terms in the sum are easy to evaluate. For example:

$\vert D_i^c \vert = (m-b+k-1)^n$ since each ball in the draw can be any one of $m-b+k-1$ balls.

$\vert D_i^c \cap D_j^c \cap D_l^c \vert = (m-b+k-3)^n$ since each ball in the draw can be any one of $m-b+k-3$ balls.

$\bigg| \bigcap_{i=1}^k{D_i^c} \bigg| = (m-b)^n$ since each ball in the draw can be any one of $m-b$ balls.

So we have now:

$$\bigg| S_k \bigg| = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{k}{(-1)^i \binom{k}{i} (m-b+k-i)^n}.$$

As stated earlier, we can choose the nominated $k$ black balls in $\binom{b}{k}$ ways so the total number of ways to get exactly $k$ distinct black balls is $\binom{b}{k} \bigg| S_k \bigg|$.

Therefore, the number of ways to get at least $k$ distinct black balls is:

$$\sum_{i=k}^b{\binom{b}{k} \bigg| S_k \bigg|}.$$

The probability of this event is then:

$$P(\text{At least $k$ distinct black balls}) = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=k}^b{\binom{b}{k} \bigg| S_k \bigg|}}{m^n}.$$

$\\$

For a numerical example, let $m=4,\; b=2,\; n=4$. We get

$$\vert S_0 \vert = 16$$

$$\vert S_1 \vert = 65$$

$$\vert S_2 \vert = 110.$$

With $k=0$ we get probability $1$ (of course).

With $k=1$ we get probability $\dfrac{240}{256}$.

With $k=2$ we get probability $\dfrac{110}{256}$.

$\\$

$2\,(c)$. Knowing the probabilities makes it easy to calculate the required averages - or "expectations" in probabilistic terms.

$$\text{Expected number of black balls drawn} = \sum_{j=0}^n{j \binom{n}{j} \left(\frac{b}{m}\right)^j \left(\frac{m-b}{m}\right)^{n-j}}.$$

$\\$

$2\,(d)$. 
$$\text{Expected number of distinct black balls drawn} = \dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^b{i \binom{b}{k} \bigg| S_k \bigg|}}{m^n}.$$

where $\vert S_k \vert$ is as given is $2\,(b)$.

---

$\\$

$3\,(a)$. Suppose we choose $b$ boxes and let their probabilities be $p_1, p_2, \ldots,p_b$.

Letting $p = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^b{p_i}$, then by the Binomial Theorem:

$$P(\text{At least $k$ balls in the $b$ boxes}) = \sum_{i=k}^n{\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}}.$$

$\\$

$3\,(b)$. The expected (i.e. average) number of balls in the chosen $b$ boxes is then just

$$\sum_{i=0}^n{i \binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}}.$$

$\\$

$3\,(c)$. We'll use a similar approach to that in $Q2\,(b)$. We firstly find the probability of getting *exactly* $k$ boxes with at least $1$ ball, then it is a simple process to sum the results as required.

So, say we nominate $k$ particular boxes. There are $t := \binom{m}{k}$ ways to do this.

Let $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_t$ be the distinct sets of $k$ boxes. For all $i$, label the boxes in $B_i$ as $b_{i_1},\ldots,b_{i_k}$ and their respective probabilities $p_{i_1},\ldots,p_{i_k}$.

For $i=1,\ldots,t$ and $j=1,\ldots,k$, define the following events:

$\quad A_i = $ "all $n$ balls are in group $B_i$"

$\quad A_{i,j} = $ "all $n$ balls are in group $B_i$ but none are in box $b_{i_j}$"

$\quad S_i = \left( \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^k{A_{i,j}} \right)^c$ where the complement is wrt $A_i$ as universal set.

$S_i$ is the event that all $n$ balls are in $B_i$ and there is at least $1$ ball in each of the $B_i$ boxes. By the [probabilistic version of the I-E principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability),

$$P(S_i) = P(A_i) - \sum_{j=1}^k{P(A_{i,j})} + \sum_{j\lt l}{P(A_{i,j} \cap A_{i,l})} - \ldots - (-1)^{k+1}P\left( \cap_{j=1}^k{A_{i,j}} \right).$$

Letting $p_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^k{p_{i_j}}$, we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A_i) &=& p_i^n \\
P(A_{i,j}) &=& (p_i - p_{i_j})^n \\
P(A_{i,j} \cap A_{i,l}) &=& (p_i - p_{i_j} - p_{i_l})^n \\
P\left( \cap_{j=1}^k{A_{i,j}} \right) &=& P(\emptyset) = 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

$$\therefore\quad P(S_i) = p_i^n - \sum_{j=1}^k{(p_i - p_{i_j})^n} + \sum_{j\lt l}{(p_i - p_{i_j} - p_{i_l})^n} - \ldots.\qquad (1)$$

Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(\text{Exactly $k$ boxes with at least $1$ ball}) &=& \sum\limits_{i=1}^t{P(S_i)} \\
&& \\
&=& \sum\limits_{s=1}^k{(-1)^{s+1}{\binom{m-s}{k-s} \sum\limits_{i_1\lt i_2 \lt \cdots \lt i_s}{\left( \sum\limits_{r=1}^s{p_{i_r}} \right)^n}}}\qquad (2)
\end{eqnarray*}

where the sum over $i_1\lt i_2 \lt \cdots \lt i_s$ means the sum over all $\binom{m}{s}$ distinct selections of $s$ elements of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$.

The RHS at $(2)$ is derived by counting the number of times any term of the form $\left( \sum\limits_{r=1}^s{p_{i_r}} \right)^n$ (summing $s$ probabilities) occurs in the RHS of $(1)$. It is the number of times a particular set of $s$ numbers appear in all $\binom{m}{k}$ selections of $k$ numbers from $m$ numbers, which means counting the number of ways to select the other $k-s$ numbers from a possible $m-s$ numbers. Hence the factor of $\binom{m-s}{k-s}$.

This is now illustrated by example.

Let $m=4, n=3, k=2$ and let the box probabilities be $0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4$. Then our formula at $(2)$ gives:

\begin{eqnarray*}
&& P(\text{Exactly $2$ boxes with at least $1$ ball}) \\
&& \quad = (-1)^2 \binom{4-1}{2-1} \left[ 0.1^3 + 0.2^3 + 0.3^3 + 0.4^3 \right] \\
&& \qquad + (-1)^3 \binom{4-2}{2-2} \left[ (0.1+0.2)^3 + (0.1+0.3)^3 + (0.1+0.4)^3 + (0.2+0.3)^3 + (0.2+0.4)^3 + (0.3+0.4)^3 +  \right] \\
&& \\
&& \quad = 0.6.
\end{eqnarray*}

Note that listing all ways for exactly $2$ boxes with at least $1$ ball to occur might help understand the counting argument above, as well as being a way to verify the result of the formula.

$\\$

$3\,(d)$. Now having the required probability, the average is straightforward:

$$E(\text{#Boxes with at least $1$ ball}) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^m{k\,P(\text{Exactly $k$ boxes with at least $1$ ball})}.$$

Comment: This answers questions 1 and 2. I'll work on question 3.

Comment: First part of #3 is there now.

Comment: @PhysicistRRE All parts are now done.